# How to design a class with constraint like a Employee cannot exist without Company and dependencies

Tags: c#, class, oop

I am trying to understand the class dependency and restrictions to follow and apply while designing a class.

Lets say I have a business rules which says that "`Employee cannot exist without Company`". Now how do I make sure that my class always follows this constraint?

I know this does not make sense:

```
public class Company

public class Employee : Company
```

because it breaks IS-A relationship because Employee is not a company.

I am just trying to understand the basic idea behind designing a class with constraints and dependencies.

I will really appreciate if someone can shed some lights in this regards :)

Comment: Single responsibility.You are checking that things in other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many design options which fulfill the requirement to discuss them all.

The simplest solution is

```
class Company
{

}

class Employee
{
    Employee(Company c) { _company = c; }
    Company _company;
}
```

That way, you ensure that an employee can only be constructed with a company, so an employee cannot exist without a comany.

Another option to fulfill the requirement is

```
class Company
{

}

class Employee
{
    Employee() { _company = new Company(); }
    Company _company;
}
```

But that way, every employee works in a different company, which is not realistic.

Yet another option is a factory method:

```
class Company
{

}

class Employee
{
    private Employee(){}
    static Employee CreateEmployee(Company c) {
       var employee = new Employee();
       employee._company = c;
       return employee;
    }
    private Company _company;
}
```

But why would you do that? It just makes it hard to find the way how to create a new object.

You can also use a builder combined with a singleton:

```
var c = new Company();
var employee = EmployeeBuilder.Instance.BuildEmployee().WithCompany(c);
```

Phew... you can do that, but you needn't.

IMHO, the best solution: an employee without a company is a person. And that person can exist without a company. You neither want the company to reference its employees, nor you want the persons to reference a company.

Employment is a relationship between a company and a person. And there can be multiple of them (n:m). My proposal would be a structure like this:

```
class Company 
{
     IList<Employment> employees;
}

class Person
{
    IList<Employment> jobs;
}

class Employment
{
    Employment(Company c, Person p){ _company = c; _person = p; }
    Person _person;
    Company _company;

    void Resign()
    {
       _person.ResignFrom(this);
       _company.ResignFrom(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but I wanted to understand the basic design and rules that we can apply to class while designing. Actually I was asked to do this in an interview. I know we can do this with some logic but interviewer wanted to understand my thought process for class design.

Comment: And it's valid to say that a) both parties have the right to resign, so it's not an aggregation or composition. b) Employment has a constructor which makes sure that both parties come together. c) The resign method of Employment ensures that both relationships are terminated at the same time.

Comment: Can you show me a small example of what I have asked in the question and how compiler can prevent it if I violate the rule please?

Comment: Thanks for the update and updating your answer to reflect my query. Why you have used Ilist instead of simple List ? Any specific purpose or reason?

Comment: IList is an interface. You could use a regular List or a SynchronizedCollection if multithreading is a thing

Comment: I am also trying to understand that what factors helps to decide to consider something as an dependency that we can inject as constructor of a class and make someone else responsibility and when we should be newing up an instance of an object inside the class? I know this are very basic questions to ask but I am just trying to learn better ways of class designing like injecting dependency vs creating new instance inside the class

Comment: What I suggested is dependency injection. The company is the dependency and it is injected into the employee. This enables you to create different compositions of objects. If you new up everything in the constructor, every object would look the same. But not everyone works at a different company. Some people work in the same company

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused: I added some more possibilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228276/discussion-between-learning-overthinker-confused-and-thomas-weller).

Comment: `void Employee(Company c)` this is not a valid syntax for a constructor

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas, your proposed scenario doesn't precisely make sense. Nonetheless, you're asking about a way to ensure that a class has a required property that references another class. Abstract classes and Interfaces might be a good way to go.

If you have an interface that creates a contract of specific properties that must be contained in a class, then any code that needs to run against the class can be guaranteed that it contains the property.

```
public class Company
{

}

public interface IEmployee
{
    Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't Employee should be a property on a company because Company has an Employee and not the opposite right?

Comment: Didn't you say in your original question that "an employee requires a company?" Thus, the interface specifies that any `IEmployee` object must have a `Company`? Perhaps if you were going to do it the opposite direction, you'd have an `ICompany` that required a property of type `List<Employee>`

Answer (score 1):

Basically the design will really depend on what are your needs:

- does employee needs to know in which company it works?
- does company needs to know who is employed by it?
- does any/both sides can resign?

You should model your domain to be usable, but at the same time as simple as possible. So in the first place you should ask what behavior you need to support before you start modelling.

Definitely the answer by [Thomas Weller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66052055/4592601) was the most flexible so let's carry on with it. You can't make your employee out of thin air, but Thomas accurately pointed out that employee is just a person with employment contract. Going forward with this - if you model an 'Employment' class it can encapsulate the rules of employment which is: for a successful employment contract both sides need to aknowledge it. When the employment is ongoing any side can resign so there is no real dependency here. This interview question was a trap ;)

I'd suggest the following solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        var company = new Company("Not an evil-corp");
        var person = new Person("John", "Doe");

        // Without person and company you can't create an employment contract, forced by constructor
        var contract = new EmploymentContract(person, company);

        // Each party can resign a contract
        //company.Resign(contract);
        //person.Resign(contract);
        contract.Resign();
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; }
    private HashSet<EmploymentContract> Contracts { get; }

    public Company(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Contracts = new HashSet<EmploymentContract>();
    }

    internal void SignContract(EmploymentContract contract)
    {
        Contracts.Add(contract);
    }

    internal void Resign(EmploymentContract contract)
    {
        if (Contracts.Remove(contract))
        {                
            contract.Resign();
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public HashSet<EmploymentContract> Contracts { get; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Contracts = new HashSet<EmploymentContract>();
    }

    internal void SignContract(EmploymentContract contract)
    {
        Contracts.Add(contract);
    }

    internal void Resign(EmploymentContract contract)
    {
        if (Contracts.Remove(contract))
        {
            contract.Resign();
        }
    }
}


public class EmploymentContract
{
    public Person Employee { get; private set; }
    public Company Employer { get; private set; }

    public EmploymentContract(Person employee, Company employer)
    {
        Employee = employee;
        Employer = employer;

        Employee.SignContract(this);
        Employer.SignContract(this);
    }

    internal void Resign()
    {
        Employee.Resign(this);
        Employer.Resign(this);

        Employee = null;
        Employer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for nice and comprehensive answer. Bdw why you have used HashSet and not a list? Just wondering

Comment: I assumed items in the Contracts collection should be unique. Otherwise you could add the same contract multiple times, HashSet guarantees that won't happen. "The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0